# Vim with syntax highlighting has slow searching in XML

Tags: syntax-highlighting, search

My experience is that Vim is slow when searching in large XML files with syntax highlighting turned on. I find it to be very dissatisfactory. I have read about the issue elsewhere but I have not been able to locate a solution. Does someone know how to treat the issue?

Comment: How large of a file are you talking about?

Comment: 40-50 megabytes, for instance.

Comment: Any text editor is going to be slow, searching in a file that large, if they can even open it.

Comment: Yes, but Sublime Text and Atom opens the same files noticeably faster. And that confuses me.

Answer (score 2):

Not a real solution, but it helps loading bigger XML files with long lines. 
This restricts the syntax hightlighting to a line width and everything after this is not highlighted. In this example there is no hightlighting after the 100th char.

```
:set synmaxcol=100
```

Or just disable syntax highlighting completely

```
:syntax off
```

(Enable with `:syntax on`)